# How can I replace curly braces with a real value inside a JSON string?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm developing an Android project. In development I use Retrofit, Gson, RxJava.

For example, such an answer may return from my server and I must replace the curly braces with real values.

```
{
    "text": "Hello {0} World {1} This is {2} test text"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) like so:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
MessageFormat.format("Hello {0} World {1} This is {2} test text", var1, var2, var3)
```

Comment: Using MessageFormat class is the easiest way to achieve this. Just remember that MessageFormat class is not synchronized, hence if you are calling a format via multiple threads, it needs to be synchronized. Or simplistically, create separate instances format for each thread.